Why doesn't clippy report all pedantic warnings in a Cargo workspace?
I have a Rust workspace crate for Rust 1.82.0. The configuration for Clippy resides inside the Cargo.toml. The configuration section for Clippy looks as follows:
[workspace.lints.rust]
rust_2024_compatibility = { level = "deny", priority = -1 }
unsafe_code = { level = "forbid", priority = 0 }

[workspace.lints.clippy]
cargo = { level = "deny", priority = -1 }
complexity = { level = "deny", priority = -1 }
correctness = { level = "deny", priority = -1 }
pedantic = { level = "deny", priority = -1 }
perf = { level = "deny", priority = -1 }
restriction = { level = "warn", priority = -1 }
style = { level = "deny", priority = -1 }

If I run cargo clippy --all-targets, no warnings are reported. However, when pedantic warnings are explicitly enabled,cargo clippy --all-targets -- -D clippy::pedantic, two errors are reported: clippy::missing_errors_doc and clippy::semicolon_if_nothing_returned.
How can that be resolved?

It turns out that the workspace crates were not set up correctly. Each crate in the workspace requires the section
[lints]
workspace = true

to be provided, in order to inherit the workspaces lint configuration.
This answer was what helped me to sort out the issue.
